# Selenium cannot find an Input type in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a form that contains some input types 'text' which selenium finds and populates ok. However it cannot find the input type submit on form, the structure looks somelike this this:

```
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="count" value="1" id="u_9_r">
```

i try

```
string get_value =  driver.FindElement(By.Name("count")).GetAttribute("value");
```

its worked and get value 1

i want change this value

i try this code

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='u_9_r']")).SendKeys("4")
```

not worked

More details
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF3EC.png)

Comment: Are you sure that, that element is visible in the web page?

Comment: I do not know you can see this photo https://prnt.sc/umzzbc

Comment: since input type is hidden `<input type='hidden' />` it won't be visible in the page, hence you can't send keys to this element

Comment: how can slove this problem

Comment: Practically, how can we type a text in textbox which is not at all visible in the page?

Comment: why do you want to send keys to this element first?

Comment: i try this code and its worked 100%
string get_value =  driver.FindElement(By.Name("count")).GetAttribute("value");

Comment: i want change value 1 to 3

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.Name("count")).SetAttribute("value", '3');

Comment: my code driver dont have SetAttribute i try this

Comment: tried JS executor?

Comment: you can give me code tried JS executor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
elem = driver.FindElement(By.Name("count"))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '3')", elem)
```